# How do I project into an object

Tags: couchbase, sql++

If I have a query like this

```
SELECT part, meta(loc).id FROM `bucket` as loc
```

it results into something like:

```
[{
   "id": "loc_006b9cfc1ef849f68b694e35c99c4dfe",
   "part": {
            "name": "foo",
            "partNumber": "1806-0085S"
           },
 } ...
```

but what if I want something like this:

```
SELECT part, { meta(loc).id } FROM `bucket` as loc  // won't work of course
```

that I would like to results into:

```
[{
   // see, this guy wrapped in its own object
   { "id": "loc_006b9cfc1ef849f68b694e35c99c4dfe" },  
   "part": {
            "name": "foo",
            "partNumber": "1806-0085S"
           },
 } ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT part, { "id": meta(loc).id } AS some_alias
FROM `bucket` as loc
```